# CSV data set config- Jmeter Docker

Tags: docker, jmeter, containers

I am creating a Jmeter docker container. Test inputs are driven from CSV(data set config). What should be filename path  that i need set in the script

Answer (score 1):

Given you're **creating** a JMeter docker container you should be aware where to drop the CSV file. Normally it is recommended to use relative paths to the CSV files in scripts for better maintainability or for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

So I would suggest using [Docker COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction in order to transfer your CSV file to JMeter's "bin" folder and use just filename in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Given the example Dockerfile from the [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how) article:

```
# 1
FROM alpine:3.6

# 2
LABEL maintainer=”vincenzo.marrazzo@domain.personal>

# 3
ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.0"

# 4
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV MIRROR_HOST http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/apache/jmeter
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL ${MIRROR_HOST}/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/

# 5
RUN    apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add ca-certificates \
    && update-ca-certificates \
            && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
            && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime \
            && echo "Europe/Rome" >  /etc/timezone \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
    && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

# 6
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-dummy/0.2/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter/0.5/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar

# 7
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

# 8
COPY launch.sh /
COPY somefile.csv $JMETER_BIN
#9
WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}

#10
ENTRYPOINT ["/launch.sh"]
```

So this line:

```
COPY somefile.csv $JMETER_BIN
```

will transfer your CSV file into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation therefore you will be able to refer it just as `somefile.csv`

Answer (score 0):

you should set the file path to the path seen from docker that is related to the volume.:

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

For example:

> docker run -v "DIR of machine":"DIR inside docker container"